# How to push or update state in NgRx?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying to add the inputVal value to the state. It only works on the first click, and getting this error after

Error: `TypeError: Cannot add property 1, object is not extensible`

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store'
import { addTodo } from '../actions/todo.actions'

export const initialState: any[] = []
let test: any[] = []

const _todoReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addTodo, (state: any, { inputVal }) => {
    test.push(inputVal)
    state = test
    return state
  })
)

export function todoReducer(state, action) {
  return _todoReducer(state, action)
}
```

How do I push or update state in NgRx? or if its not possible, what's the work around for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never modify a `state` in `NgRx`, the reducer will return a new copy of state rather than modifying the existing one. So you can't add `test` to `state`

try

```
const _todoReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addTodo, (state: any, { inputVal }) => {
    return [...state,inputVal] // we are creating a new array and this will become the new state.
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, in your component please inject Store
`constructor(private store:Store){..}`

Store can be updated via `this.store.dispatch(addTodo("element"))`

but there is another problem. Your store should be immutable, so you cannot reuse `test` array in reducer.

```
const _todoReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addTodo, (state: any, { inputVal }) => {
    return [...state, inputVal]
  })
)
```

is enough.